# python multiprocessing and matplotlip.pyplots don't cooperate appropriately

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, multiprocessing

I spawned a child process with the help of pythons *multiprocessing* module. Among other things the process' task is to plot some data. Unfortunatley it does not even execute a single *matplotlib.pyplot* method. I reproduced the problem within a few lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mp

def plot():
    print("CODE BEFORE")
    plt.scatter(1, 1)
    print("CODE AFTER")

p = mp.Process(target=plot)
p.start()
p.join()
```

The output is:

> CODE BEFORE

Anybody able to clarify the issue ?

Comment: It works on my machine (I can see both outputs); maybe an issue with matplotlib?

Comment: [link](https://repl.it/repls/ExtralargeGrippingComputers) getting both output.

Comment: True. That's weird. I just found out, that it works if I import the module matplotlib.pyplot directly within the plot function